# Type errors for d3js in Angular ( Latest )

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I've noticed there are many type errors for d3js when using it with Angular(typescript).
For example I can't get the following snippet to work

```
svg.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', () => {
      g.attr('transform', d3.events.transform);
    }));
```

Throws

```
S2345: Argument of type 'ZoomBehavior<Element, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(selection: Selection<BaseType, unknown, HTMLElement, any>, ...args: any[]) => void'.   Types of parameters 'selection' and 'selection' are incompatible.     Type 'Selection<BaseType, unknown, HTMLElement, any>' is not assignable to type 'Selection<Element, unknown, any, any>'.       Types of property 'select' are incompatible.         Type '{ <DescElement extends BaseType>(selector: string): Selection<DescElement, unknown, HTMLElement, any>; <DescElement extends BaseType>(selector: null): Selection<null, undefined, HTMLElement, any>; <DescElement extends BaseType>(selector: ValueFn<...>): Selection<...>; }' is not assignable to type '{ <DescElement extends BaseType>(selector: string): Selection<DescElement, unknown, any, any>; <DescElement extends BaseType>(selector: null): Selection<null, undefined, any, any>; <DescElement extends BaseType>(selector: ValueFn<...>): Selection<...>; }'.           Types of parameters 'selector' and 'selector' are incompatible.             Types of parameters 'groups' and 'groups' are incompatible.               Type 'BaseType[] | ArrayLike<BaseType>' is not assignable to type 'Element[] | ArrayLike<Element>'.                 Type 'BaseType[]' is not assignable to type 'Element[] | ArrayLike<Element>'.                   Type 'BaseType[]' is not assignable to type 'Element[]'.                     Type 'BaseType' is not assignable to type 'Element'.                       Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
```

Also, another error is that d3.events is undefined.

Any tips on how to get this working? There are multiple code samples that just don't work due to type errors. Even suppressing with @ts-ignore doesn't solve them.

UPDATE: After using the migrations guide from v5 to v6, the zoom handler doesn't throw any more errors

```
const zoom = d3.zoom().on('zoom', ({transform}, d) => {
   g.attr('transform', transform);
});
```

But there still is the type error when trying to call it like this

```
svg.call(zoom)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

About '`d3.event` is undefined':

If you get the type error that `d3.event` is undefined, but `d3.event` works when you run the application, this means that the `@types/d3` package is in the version that matches d3 v6, while the d3 package itself is on d3 v5. This error happens because of [the changes between d3 v5 and v6](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide), which includes the removal of `d3.event`.

You can see the types versions [in the npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3). They roughly match d3 versions, so the one you're looking for is `@types/d3@5.16.4`.

About the type error:

If you don't define the type of the selection, it defaults to `Selection<BaseType, unknown, HTMLElement, any>`. However, the `d3.zoom` defaults to `ZoomBehavior<Element, unknown>`. The issue is that typescript complains that `BaseType` and `Element` are not compatible.

To fix it, you can define the svg selection and the zoom with explicit generics:

```js
const svg = d3.select<SVGSVGElement, unknown>(...);
const zoom = d3.zoom<SVGSVGElement, unknown>() [...];

svg.call(zoom);
```

The first line says you're selecting an `SVGSVGElement` (the type of the `<svg>` element) that has `unknown` datum. The second line says that the zoom will be called on a selection of `SVGSVGElement` that also has an `unknown` datum type.

Now the generics of both zoom and svg match, and the `.call` method will be compatile. Here is a [codesandbox that demonstrates it](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-williamson-txx3w).

Comment: Both packages are v6.  I actually never use @ts-ignore, that's why I posted this question here.

Comment: Update: Changing both packages to 5.16.0 fixed the type error. The d3.event is still undefined

Comment: [comment before the update] In that case you might want to check the [v6 migration guide](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide), because d3.event was removed. I also personally dislike ts-ignore too, but some issues (for example in `TransitionLike` type and `d3.hierarchy`) are best ignored when I trust what the code and d3 are doing.

Comment: [after the update] d3.event is defined on v5, if it is undefined it means something else is causing d3 to be in v6. Do you have a separate d3-selection installation?

Comment: Thank you very much for that migration guide. I'm new to d3 and apparently none of the snippets were updated to v6, nor are marked as deprecated. This sheds some light.

Comment: I just noticed on the question snipped that it is using `d3.events` instead of `d3.event`, this could be the cause of the error if it is on the code too.

Comment: I had misunderstood the cause of the error in my first answer. I edited it now.

Comment: Still wouldn't work. Also, you can only specify the type of element and type of datum. The return type contains all 4 types.

Comment: Oops, you're correct, I confused with the generics definitions of the `selection` method with the `Selection` type. What was missing to fix the error was the generics of the `d3.zoom`, I edited the answer and added a codesandbox to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `@types/d3@5.16.4` - it works! Before I tried `@types/d3@5.7.2` and it did not recognize `d3.event` ... apparently this version was subsequently updated and is no longer compatibale with `d3@5.x.y`.

Comment: Thank you so much by adding <SVGSVGElement, unknown> to d3.zoom it fixed my issue!